# How to create ASYNC POST API that takes JSON list objects as an argument and there are multiple requests? How to test miltiple request in Postman?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, concurrency, async-await

The code that is posted is the way I want to solve the problem, but it doesn't work. So, the method receives a list of JSON objects, then the post method needs to pass it to the database.

```
    public async Task<bool> Post(string requestUri, IEnumerable<DailyForecast> listFromUI)
    {

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            bool success = true;
            
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(requestUri), new HttpListContent(listFromUI));
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return success;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             success = false;

            return success;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to create post method for multiple requests. The endpoint accepts a json list and saves it to the database.

I've never used async before so I'm not sure if the code posted above is useful at all.